# Given $f : A \rightarrow B \::\:\forall\: a_1, a_2 \in A,\:a_1 \leq a_2 \implies f(a_1) \leq f(a_2)$.

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are nonempty subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, and that $f : A \rightarrow B$ is a function satisfying $\forall\: a_1, a_2 \in A,\:a_1 \leq a_2 \implies f(a_1) \leq f(a_2)$.

(Such a function is said to be weakly increasing.) Furthermore, suppose that $f$ is surjective

(i) Prove that if $M$ is a largest element of $A$, then $f(M)$ is a largest element of $B$.

(ii) Why is the assumption that $f$ is surjective necessary? Give an example of nonempty subsets $A$ and $B$
of $\mathbb{R}$, a weakly increasing function $f : A \rightarrow B$, and a largest element $M$ of $A$ such that $f(M)$ is not a
largest element of $B$.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of making some formatting adjustments to your post, fixing the tags, and trying to make the title more helpful. I'm not certain what "a largest element" means. Do you mean "the greatest element," possibly? Also, your questions will be more likely to gain attention if you include your thoughts and efforts, to help us gauge your experience level.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.*
From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/). Welcome to Math.SE!

Answer (score 1):

Counter-example in (ii):
Let $A=\{0\}$ and $B=\{0,1\}$. Define $f:A\rightarrow B$ by $f(0)=0$. Clearly, $A,B$ are non-empty subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ and $f$ is "weaking increasing". Moreover $0$ is the largest element of $A$. However, $f(0)=0$ is not the largest element of $B$.

//////////////////////////////////

To prove (i). Let $y\in B$. Since $f$ is surjective, there exists $x\in A$ such that $f(x)=y$. Now $x\leq M$, so $y=f(x)\leq f(M)$. This shows that $f(M)$ is the largest element in $B$.